# Xcode SVN Error: Attempted to lock an already-locked dir, How to solve?

Tags: iphone, svn, xcode

Error: 155004 (Attempted to lock an already-locked dir) Description: Working copy '/Users/Carrie/MyProjects/Sandbox/Flip/Classes' locked

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
cd <root of svn>
svn cleanup
```

More info [here](http://mindspill.net/computing/linux-notes/subversion-svn/locked-cleanup-not-a-working-copy.html)

Comment: also need to cleanup the "Class" dir in it.